# Calling $destroy on angularfire arrays and objects when offline

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I understand that if a device is not connected to the internet, angularfire will queue tasks to be performed when the connection is re-established. In the interests of preventing memory leaks, I would like to sever all watchers when tasks are completed, by calling `$destroy`. I am worried that if I for example, call the `$add` or `$remove` methods on an array, then call `$destroy` after `.then()` to remove the now unused connection, I will prevent the add or remove methods completing when back online. Could somebody please clarify if this is the case, and if so how I might delay the `$destroy` method until queued tasks on the connection are completed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following testing I can confirm that methods are executed on re-connect then the watchers removed.